# How do I get the difference between two datetimes in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, datediff

I'm trying this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,log.start_time,log.end_time) 
as seconds 
from log 
where log.log_id = "some crazy UUID";
```

but I get an error because `DATEDIFF()` accepts no formatter expr like second.

So I tried,

```
SELECT second(DATEDIFF(second,log.start_time,log.end_time)) 
as seconds 
from log
where log.log_id = "some crazy UUID";
```

But that doesn't work for formatting either.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) instead of `DATEDIFF()`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,log.start_time,log.end_time) as seconds 
from log 
where log.log_id = "some crazy UUID";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( log.start_time, log.end_time )) AS seconds
FROM log 
WHERE log.log_id = "some crazy UUID";
```

Answer (score 2):

`DATEDIFF()` returns days of difference.

Use `TIMEDIFF()` or convert both timestamps with `TO_SECONDS()`) and get their difference:

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS(log.end_time) - TO_SECONDS(log.start_time) AS seconds
  FROM log 
  WHERE log.log_id = "some crazy UUID"
;
```

Answer (score 2):

DATEDIFF accept only two parameters and you are passing three parameters here.

How it works and also it returns only the difference b/w dates not including time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

**DATEDIFF** :

From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), it returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate. The `DATEDIFF()` function returns the time between two dates.
Syntax :

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

You should use `TIMEDIFF()` or `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function.
Just replace `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function with `DATEFDIFF()`